# RxAndroidBle - How to receive writeCharacteristic on Mocked Device

Tags: rxandroidble

I'm trying to send a "hello" to mocked device and receive a feedback from it. I use writeCharacteristic to mocked Device but i dont know how to setup the response from it.

Please help, many thanks !!!

```
@OnClick(R.id.write)
public void onWriteClick() {

    SoftCheckConnected();

    connectionObservable
            .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(characteristicUuid, getInputBytes()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(bytes -> {
                String result = new String(bytes);
                onWriteStatus(result.trim().equals("Hello pin"));
            }, this::onWriteFailure);

}
```

For mocked device

```
 RxBleDevice bleDevice = new RxBleClientMock.DeviceBuilder()
            .deviceMacAddress("AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF")
            .deviceName("TestDevice")
            .scanRecord("ScanRecord".getBytes())
            .rssi(42)
            .notificationSource(characteristicNotifiedUUID, characteristicNotificationSubject)
            .addService(
                    serviceUUID,
                    new RxBleClientMock.CharacteristicsBuilder()
                            .addCharacteristic(
                                    characteristicUUID,
                                    characteristicData,
                                    new RxBleClientMock.DescriptorsBuilder()
                                            .addDescriptor(descriptorUUID, descriptorData)
                                            .build()
                            ).build()
            ).build();
```

Comment: any ideas for this ? =(